# how to upload a docx in Kentico and after show it in aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, kentico

I have a Word Document (docx), in which I have the "terms of use".

How can i upload this Word Document in Kentico and display it when the users clicks the link to the "Terms of use"?

Comment: If you could be a bit more specific. Where is the link? Is it a existing link? can you modify your link? do you want to solve the problem with or without programming? ... ? I could give you an answer, but how the question is state, i am pretty sure it wont the solution you are looking for.

Comment: it is the typical link appears in any page to show a box with the conditions, I was clear, only show, imagine when you want to insert some user data you want to show the information isnide (never to modify it). I need because frequently I arecieve some document about user data protection and maybe uin Kentico has some utility to upload first in CMS and after clicking in that link open a dialog box with taht information, only, I repeat, to show.

Comment: I'm really sorry i donno what exactly what you need. Cant you just upload the document in the CMS and copy the URL (to that Document) from the properties Tab? I am confused

Comment: my idea is to use something like sharepoint where you can upload a document and show it in your web page. The problem I am using Kentico (looks like CMS) but I don't know if I have this posibility. I hope this comment helped you.

Comment: In the Backend you can do such thinks, look at the [Documentation](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/6_0/devguide/index.html?attachments_overview.htm). I hope this helps, to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to upload a .docx you have to add it to the "Upload extensions" list under the site settings.  In version 7 and before you had to log in to the CMS Site Manager, click on Settings > System > Files.  Here is a walk through for Kentico 8: https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Importing+files

Any link you provide to a document should default to .aspx, unless you've changed this setting. It should also be available by the file type extension by default.